# Get intersected Rect!

Tags: iphone

I found the following function CGRectIntersectsRect (frame1,frame2)
which returns true if they are intersected.
Is there another function that returns the intersected Rect?

Answer (score 3):

> **CGRectIntersection** Returns the intersection of two rectangles.

```
CGRect CGRectIntersection (
   CGRect r1,
   CGRect r2
);
```